# get array of number of days of specified day with moment.js

Tags: date, momentjs

there is a way to obtain an array with day numbers of a specified month (current month) of a specified day name?

E.g. I want to obtain all Saturdays of June 2016.

I would like to have the array with [4,11,18,25] values. (4th June is Saturday, 11 too, and so on...).

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. Suppose that I want to obtain all Sundeys (so call function with 0 that is the number for Sundays)

```
function getDays(num){
    var dArray = new Array();
    var cMonth = moment().get('month');
    dArray.push(moment().day(num));
    if (moment().day(num-7).get('month') == cMonth) {dArray.push(moment().day(num-7));}
    if (moment().day(num-14).get('month') == cMonth) {dArray.push(moment().day(num-14));}
    if (moment().day(num-21).get('month') == cMonth) {dArray.push(moment().day(num-21));}
    if (moment().day(num-28).get('month') == cMonth) {dArray.push(moment().day(num-28));}
    if (moment().day(num+7).get('month') == cMonth) {dArray.push(moment().day(num+7));}
    if (moment().day(num+14).get('month') == cMonth) {dArray.push(moment().day(num+14));}
    if (moment().day(num+21).get('month') == cMonth) {dArray.push(moment().day(num+21));}
    if (moment().day(num+28).get('month') == cMonth) {dArray.push(moment().day(num+28));}
    return dArray;
};
```